# How stable is Chrome ARC Storage?

Tags: google-chrome-arc

Is there a case when data would be erased (i.e. looking like clean install of app) besides using the Remove App feature?

I know the Downloads folder could be erased automatically if the device runs low on internal storage. What about my app?

Also, is there some kind of magical quota where app data would get deleted?

Comment: A less specific question: [What happens when a Chromebook runs out of internal space?](http://superuser.com/questions/1132267/what-happens-when-a-chromebook-runs-out-of-internal-space)